# The Ecosystem Metadata Exchange tool fails to synchronize with sysdev.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I've been trying to synchronize my company's products metadata using MEME, but it consistently fails. It authenticates fine, but when it comes to actually pulling the product list it always fails. What's interesting is that it always seems to fail at the same time, leaving the file lists of the products only partially filled. Windows event log says (in short): "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." Has anybody seen something similar? If not, can you point me to the best place to find more information about this? It seems there's precious few resources for MEME online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed now :) I had the same problem and contacted the dev´s at microsoft. They fixed 2 bugs in the server side part of it. It works fine now for me. You might want to try again?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving indicates a server side error. To get help from Microsoft do the following:

1. Use the "send logs to microsoft" (from within the MEME application)
2. Find the detailed error trace in the event log Contact Windows Error
3. Reporting support at: wer@microsoft.com

Dont worry if you get some bounches when sending to the email address, some people at Microsoft will get the mail, and they are normally very helpfull.